# Using Html.EditorFor() for custom type in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom type Money for my ViewModel:

```
public class Money
{
    public Money(decimal value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public decimal Value { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0:0.00}", Value);
    }
}
```

and I want to render a textbox in ASP.NET MVC via `HTML.EditorFor(viewModel => viewModel.MyMoneyProperty)` but it doesn't work. Is there a special interface which I have to implement in Money?

Best regards and thanks in advance,

Steffen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public class Money
{
    public Money(decimal value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }
}
```

and in your view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomePropertyOfTypeMoney.Value) %>
```

Or you could have a custom editor template for Money (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Money.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.Money>" 
%>
<%= Html.TextBox("", Model.Value.ToString("0.00")) %>
```

and then in your view:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomePropertyOfTypeMoney) %>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot. I added a Text property and did the converting stuff in the getter and setter. Then I bound it in the view.

Comment: One problem still remains. Now all ids in the HTML code are suffixed with _text. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @forki23, this happens because you added a `Text` property and the textbox helper is using it. You might need a custom helper that modifies the ids but this is something I wouldn't do. Leave the helper generate whatever ids it like because this way they will be guaranteed to be unique. If you start messing with the ids there is a risk.